# MySQL intermediary table error code 1005 (150) can't create foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which i want to join with an intermediary table for a many to many relationship

the first table is booking

```
CREATE TABLE booking (
    bookingID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    customerID INT,
    runID INT,
    startDate DATE,
    endDate DATE,
    dateBookedOn  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (bookingID),
    INDEX idx_start (startDate),
    INDEX idx_end (endDate),
    FOREIGN KEY (runID) REFERENCES Run(RunID),
    FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES customer(CustomerID));
```

the second is dog

```
CREATE TABLE dog(
    DogID int(6) NOT NULL,
    DogName varchar(15),
    medicalID int (6),
    Gender character(1) check(gender in ('m', 'f')),
    Age int(2),
    Breed varchar(15),
    size character (1) check(size in ('s', 'm', 'l')),
    primary key (DogID));
```

and the intermediary table is as follows which gives an error 1005(150) there is something wrong with the foreign key for bookingID. But can't see the problem. any help is welcomed.

```
CREATE TABLE isBooked(
    BookingID int not null,
    DogID int not null,
    foreign key (DogID) references Dog(dogID),
    foreign key (BookingID) references Booking(BookingID));
```

Comment: Your DOG table has `DogID int(6) NOT NULL,` and you are trying to reference from `isBooked` and it is defined in this way `DogID int not null,`. Types and size must match.

Comment: the two fields have to be identically defined. while an int is an int, `int(6)` is still a different definition on dog.DogID